# C++: Assign L"" string to WCHAR[]?

Tags: c++, string

I have a WCHAR[]:

```
WCHAR foo[200];
```

I want to copy values into it:

```
if (condition)
{
    foo = L"bar";
}
else 
{
   foo = L"odp";
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you need to do, you could change the type of foo:

```
const WCHAR *foo;
if (condition)
{
    foo = L"bar";
}
else 
{
   foo = L"odp";
}
```

This is fine if don't need to append any more data to foo.

Answer (score 8):

[`wcscpy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663%28VS.80%29.aspx), although the superbest thing would be to use [`std::wstring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55%28VS.80%29.aspx) instead.

```
std::wstring foo;
if (condition)
    foo = L"bar";
else 
    foo = L"odp";
```

Or if you insist on using `wcscpy`:

```
WCHAR foo[200];
if (condition)
    wcscpy(foo, L"bar");
else 
    wcscpy(foo, L"odp");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::wstring` instead of a `WCHAR` array.

```
std::wstring foo;

...

if (condition)
{
    foo = L"bar";
}
else 
{
   foo = L"odp";
}
```

The alternative would be to use some dirty wstrcpy functions coming from the C world, what is not approriate or safe if you can go the cleaner C++ way.

Comment: Same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010190/94687 , which is better rated. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about assigning a value, the way you are doing it is perfect. If you are using Visual C++ and want to copy w-strings consider using the more secure function [wcscpy_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (it is more secure than wcscpy).

```
errno_t wcscpy_s(
   wchar_t *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const wchar_t *strSource 
);
```

I'll give you a short example:

```
wchar* wstrOther = "hello";
wcscpy_s(foo, 200, wstrOther);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `foo` variable is actually a pointer to the first char of the string. So assigning another string to it will just replace the pointer and leak memory.

The simplest way to do this is using a string class, like `std::wstring`, or using some old C functions like `strncpy`.

Using srd::wstring it would look like:

```
std::wstring foo;

if(condition)
{
   foo = L"bar";
}
else
{
   foo = L"odp";
}
```

Comment: Same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010190/94687 , which is better rated. :(